# Application.Current "null" in console application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, f#

I'm currently trying to use a WPF component that makes use of Application.Current from a WPF application, however due to several reasons I never call Application.Run (nor is that an option). The result is a NullReferenceException.

I'm basically trying to display multiple instances of the same WPF window from what would be a console application.
Any advice (and code samples in C#/F#) would be welcome!

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you don't `Run()` an application, you don't have an `Application`.  What are you doing?

Comment: Aaah, the joys of using WPF controls outside of a WPF application.

Comment: I'm trying to show WPF windows from a multithreaded console application. Cases of the same window being shown multiple times can and will occur, too, so the situation is not too easy! :/

Comment: But why aren't you calling `Run()`? How are you getting a message loop>

Comment: My main problem is not so much Run, but the fact that if I close one window after Run I won't be able to spawn another right after. Along with that, there's the fact that Application.LoadComponent is giving me headaches for it won't load the same xaml twice and throw some exception

Comment: If you don't run an Application why do you need Application.Current ? Something wrong with design of your application lifecycle.

Comment: @emaster70 You need `Run`. Create a hidden window to be your main window and then you can close a window and spawn another without terminating app. And now I can see that the answer below says exactly this. That's the solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just to offer an alternative solution. 
It is possible to keep an application running without any windows open. To me this feels less 'hackish'. :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx

```
public class AppCode : Application
{
   // Entry point method
   [STAThread]
   public static void Main()
   {
      AppCode app = new AppCode();
      app.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;
      app.Run();
      ...
      app.Shutdown();
   }
}
```

EDIT: 
Ok this got a bit cumbersome. Application.Run will block, so it needs to run in its own thread. 
When it does run in its own thread, any interaction between your main thread and your ui thread had best be done by Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke. Here is some working code, that assumes you have a class that inherits from Application. I'm using a modified App.xaml/App.xaml.cs that a WPF project template creates for you, to get nice handling of ResourceDictionaries for free.

```
public class Program
{
  // Entry point method
  [STAThread]
  public static void Main()
  {
     var thread = new System.Threading.Thread(CreateApp);
     thread.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
     thread.Start();

     // This is kinda shoddy, but the thread needs some time 
     // before we can invoke anything on the dispatcher
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);

     // In order to get input from the user, display a
     // dialog and return the result on the dispatcher
     var result = (int)Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Func<int>(() =>
        {
           var win = new MainWindow();
           win.ShowDialog();
           return 10;
        }), null);

     // Show something to the user without waiting for a result
     Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
     {
        var win = new MainWindow();
        win.ShowDialog();
     }), null);

     System.Console.WriteLine("result" + result);
     System.Console.ReadLine();

     // This doesn't really seem necessary 
     Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
  }

  private static void CreateApp()
  {
     App app = new App();
     app.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;
     app.Run();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this sounds good, however I'm actually using the hidden window's dispatcher thread to create and show other windows. How would I do so in your example?

Comment: Never knew about `ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown`. Thanks for posting that -- alot of people who build tray applications in WPF are looking for something like that.

Answer (score 6):

The following is the intended behavior of Application class:

- The first open window is the MainWindow.
- The only window in the list becomes the MainWindow (if others are to
  be removed).
- Application Class is designed to exit if no windows are present in
  windows list.

Check this [link](http://www.ageektrapped.com/blog/the-wpf-application-class-overview-and-gotcha/).

So basically you cannot run an Application, without any window open. Keep a window open but hidden.

---

If I have misunderstood your problem, then perhaps the following similar cases might help:

- [Managing Application Resources when WPF is Hosted](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/10/05/managing-application-resources-when-wpf-is-hosted/).
- [When running unit tests in Visual Studio 2008](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/786d5c06-0511-41c0-a6a2-5c4e44f8ffb6/)

Comment: I ended up running as you suggested a hidden window. In the context of that window, via Dispatcher.Invoke calls I instantiate and .Show() the other windows. That sounds all quite nasty but for the time being it works :)

Comment: Well from the compiler's point of view, your program without a window was nasty :p